# Call SQL Server procedure using batch script and store the result log in file

Tags: sql, sql-server, spritebatch

I need to write a batch script that calls a SQL Server query and runs a procedure in a SQL Server database and stores the result log in a file.

Comment: Ummmm....how could we do that? You have provided exactly no information at all.

Comment: Sounds like Friday afternoon homework assignment for the weekend!

Comment: Here I am trying to think of what kinds of sprites someone would want to store in a log file...

Comment: I think you can do that using the SQLCMD command.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .bat file with contents like this:

```
cd %0\..
  sqlcmd -S YourServerName -d "YourdatabaseName" -U SqlLonginuserName -P Password -o "C:\Script_Output.txt" -p 1 -i "c:\LocationOfSQLScript.sql"
```